# IntelliJ during debug does not show the values in Spring RedirectAttributes

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

When the code reaches the break point `return`, I am expecting to see at least some value added in `redirAttr` but the debug variable shows the size of `0`. Does anyone know why I don't see anything? Using `IntelliJ`

```
@RequestMapping(value="/hello", method=POST)
public String hello(final RedirectAttributes redirAttr)
{
    redirAttr.addFlashAttribute("objects", listOfObjects);        

    return "redirect:/somewhere.htm";
}
```

redirAttr is of size `0` when the break point reaches `return`

Comment: what variable is size 0 exactly?

Comment: redirAttr is of size `0` when the break point reaches `return`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default implementation of `RedirectAttributes` -  `RedirectAttributesModelMap` extends `ModelMap` but uses it only for normal (non-flash) attributes. You can add those with `RedirectAttributes.addAttribute(...)` methods.

Internally, that implementation uses additional `ModelMap` to store flash attributes:

```
private final ModelMap flashAttributes = new ModelMap();
```

Size of that structure should change as expected when executing your code.

Answer (score 0):

To see the size and content of Redirect attributes in debugger:

```
redirectAttributes.getFlashAttributes()
```